# how to create a dynamic tree structure using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make a dynamic tree structure using jquery and css which is having the following structure

Level 1 
       - Level 1a 
               options
                      Yes or No
If Yes 
      - Level 1a
              Yes or No (dynamic)

If No
      - Level 1a
              Yes or No (dynamic)

[image: Reference Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution , i hope this would be helpful for your problem.

```
<form name="f1" method="post" action="">
<div id="container">
<ul>

<li><input type="text" id="txt_1" name="q_0_1" class="margin_top_o"></li>
<li  class="margin_left ">
 <span class="tree-connector">No</span>
<input type="text" id="txt_2" value="Y_1" name="Y_1" class="margin_ng">

<div class="romvebtn">
<button type="button" id="2" class="remove ">Remove</button>
</div>
<button type="button" id="1" class="ul-appending ">Expand</button></li>
<li  class="tree-lastsib">
<span class="tree-connector">Yes</span>
<input type="text" id="txt_3" value="Y_2" name="Y_2" class="margin_ng">
<div class="romvebtn">
<button type="button" id="2" class="remove ">Remove</button>
</div>
<button type="button" id="2" class="ul-appending tt">Expand</button></li>
</ul>
</div>
</form>
```

[for more details plese review this link.](http://jsfiddle.net/t2Wc9/2/)